# Error updating database - Cpanel PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, cpanel

I'm having trouble inserting data into a database I created using `cpanel`. I keep getting an error when I try submitting my form.

**I created this form in `html`:**

```
<form  action="employees.php" method="post">
    <div>
                <div >
                    <label for="inputFN">FIRST NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inputFN"/>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <label for="inputLN">LAST NAME</label>
                    <input type="text" name="inputLN"/>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="inputTitle">TITLE</label>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <select name="title_select_container">
                            <option value="Select">-- * SELECT * --</option>
                            <option value="Operator">Operator</option>
            <option value="Manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="Contractor">Contractor</option>
            <option value="Worker">Worker</option>
            <option value="none">NO LONGER EMPLOYED</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="jobCode">JOB CODE</label>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <select name="jobCode_select_container">
                            <option value="Select">-- * SELECT * --</option>
                            <option value="141802">141802BENT</option>
            <option value="141803B">141803BENT</option>
            <option value="141904Z">141904ZOO</option>
            <option value="142405T">142405TEK</option>
            <option value="NEW">--NEW--</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="text" id="newJobCode"/>
                        <input type="button" id="btnNewJobCode" value="Add"/>
                    </div>
                    <script>
                        $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#newJobCode').hide();
                    $('#btnNewJobCode').hide();

                    $("#jobCode_select_container").change(function() {
                    var val = $(this).val();

                    if (val == 'NEW') {
                        $('#newJobCode').show();
                        $('#btnNewJobCode').show();
                    } else {
                        $('#newJobCode').hide();
                        $('#btnNewJobCode').hide();
                    }
                }).change();

            }); 
        </script>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="lblActivity">Activity</label>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <select name="activity_select_container">
                            <option value="Select">-- * SELECT * --</option>
            <option value="W">Working</option>
            <option value="I">Inactive</option>
                        </select>
        </div>
                    </div>
                <input type="submit"></form>
```

**And this is my `php` file to handle it:**

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db('a_db') or die(mysql_error()); 

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputFN']);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputLN']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title_select_container']);
$jobCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jobCode_select_container']);
$activity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['activity_select_container']);

$query="INSERT INTO tblEmployees (empFirstName, empLastName, empTitle ,jobCode, empActivity) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$title', '$jobCode', '$activity');";

mysql_query( $query ) or die( 'Error updating database' );
echo "Database Updated With: " .$firstname. " ".$lastname." ".$title." ".$jobCode." ".$activity ;

?>
```

**And this is how my table is set up**:
[image: tblEmployee set up]

I figure something might be wrong with my `insert` statement but I can't tell what it is because I follow the same syntax on other pages (with forms without `select` dropdowns), and everything is processed fine.

I also want to be able to present this data on a `table` on the webpage itself. But can't begin to do that unless I can at least insert data.

**Update:**
Using @Fred-ii- 's reporting suggestion, the lines in question are these in the `php`:

```
$title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title_select_container']);
$jobCode=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jobCode_select_container']);
$activity=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['activity_select_container']);
```

Error:

```
Undefined index: title_select_container in employees.php
Undefined index: jobCode_select_container in employees.php
Undefined index: activity_select_container in employees.php
```

I thought the `select` element is "form control and can be used in a form to collect user input", so why can it not retrieve the values?

Comment: You're not treating your columns as columns in `('empFirstName', 'empLastName',...` remove the quotes, or use backticks. Plus, you may need to use quotes around `$jobCode, $activity` since they're `VARCHAR`. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Also, you need a semicolon at the end of the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried those changes and the problem persists. Do I insert that `error_reporting` in the `php`?

Comment: @JonathanM Same error.

Comment: Yes, place the codes I've given you, under the opening/starting `<?php` tag. As in `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); // rest of code`

Comment: Try `(empFirstName, empLastName, empTitle, jobCode, empActivity) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$title', '$jobCode', '$activity')`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Alright added, updated post with the error. Seems exclusive to my `select` boxes.

Comment: The problem is (or one of them) here `<select name="title_select" name="title_select_container">` you gave it two names. Remove `name="title_select"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Removed, noticed that as well. Error still persists.

Comment: I have no idea, other than using `if(isset($_POST['element_name']))`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks though! There was a problem with the `$query` line like you pointed out, just a matter of getting it right. Also had to change the singlequotes in the connection line to double...odd, but worked somehow. x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Id suggest trying the following

```
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die(mysql_error()); 

mysql_select_db('a_db') or die(mysql_error()); 

// escape variables for security
$firstname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputFN']);
$lastname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputLN']);
$title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title_select_container']);
$jobCode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jobCode_select_container']);
$activity = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['activity_select_container']);    

$query="INSERT INTO tblEmployees(`empFirstName`, `empLastName`, `empTitle` ,`jobCode`, `empActivity`) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$title', '$jobCode', '$activity')";

mysql_query( $query ) or die( 'Error updating database' );
echo "Database Updated With: " .$firstname. " ".$lastname." ".$title." ".$jobCode." ".$activity ;

?>
```

Also the

```
Undefined index: title_select_container in employees.php
Undefined index: jobCode_select_container in employees.php
Undefined index: activity_select_container in employees.php
```

This part is stating that it cannot find title_select_container within that file so your best adding isset() around your or an if statement to check if form is posted

Comment: Thanks! Led to a working solution. I had to also change the connection line from single quotes ('localhost') to double quotes ("localhost"). Strange...as that doesn't seem to effect my other php files.  I will include an `isset()` as well. :)